# Localize current time in PHP

Tags: php, time, string, hebrew, localization

Trying to display current time with PHP (using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470617/get-current-date-and-time-in-php)):

```
$date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());                      
echo $date;
```

As simple as it gets. How do I localize it? I want to translate the months and days to Hebrew.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Zend_Date`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.date.html#zend.date.why) is completely internationalized. You should check that out for a simple way to do it:

> All full and abbreviated names of
>   months and weekdays are supported for
>   more than 130 languages. Methods
>   support both input and the output of
>   dates using the localized names of
>   months and weekdays, in the
>   conventional format associated with
>   each locale.

Comment: The simple solution I was looking for. Danke.

Comment: Doesn't this assume that you have to be using the zend framework? which isn't mentioned in the question.

Comment: @WebDevHobo - no, you don't have to use the whole thing, its componenents are loosely coupled by design.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, I don't think it is quite possible in PHP 5.2 :-(

At least, not with what's bundled with/in PHP *(There are libraries coded in PHP that you could use, though, like other answers pointed out)*

With PHP 5.3, though, you have the [IntlDateFormatter](http://php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php) class, which does exactly what you want :

> This class represents the ICU date
>   formatting functionality. It allows
>   users to display dates in a localized
>   format or to parse strings into PHP
>   date values using pattern strings
>   and/or canned patterns.

For instance, using that class, like this :

```
echo IntlDateFormatter::create('fr_FR', IntlDateFormatter::FULL, IntlDateFormatter::FULL)->format(time(time())) . "\n";
echo IntlDateFormatter::create('fr_FR', IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM, IntlDateFormatter::SHORT)->format(time(time())) . "\n";

echo IntlDateFormatter::create('zh-Hant-TW', IntlDateFormatter::FULL, IntlDateFormatter::FULL)->format(time(time())) . "\n";
echo IntlDateFormatter::create('zh-Hant-TW', IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM, IntlDateFormatter::SHORT)->format(time(time())) . "\n";

echo IntlDateFormatter::create('en_US', IntlDateFormatter::FULL, IntlDateFormatter::FULL)->format(time(time())) . "\n";
echo IntlDateFormatter::create('en_US', IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM, IntlDateFormatter::SHORT)->format(time(time())) . "\n";
```

You'd get :

```
dimanche 9 novembre 2008 23:54:47 GMT+00:00
9 nov. 2008 23:54
2008年11月9日星期日 下午11時54分47秒 GMT+00:00
2008/11/9 下午 11:54
Sunday, November 9, 2008 11:54:47 PM GMT+00:00
Nov 9, 2008 11:54 PM
```

Which looks quite nice, doesn't it ?

Sad thing is PHP 5.3 is only a few months old, and not available on many hosting services... And will require testing (and probably fixes) for your application...

Thinking about it : maybe you can install the [PECL intl extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/intl) on PHP 5.2, though, and get the same functionnality...

Comment: It may be worth noting that IntlDateFormatter::format($time) will fail silently if $time is a string. Make sure that you always pass an integer! (Tested with Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and PHP 5.3.)

Answer (score 2):

If you need a more simple way than Zend_Date and IntlDateFormatter try the standard `strftime` function in php. Here's the stuff I did to get it up and running with the Russian language running php 5.3 on Ubuntu (Russian locale was not installed).

To install locale

1. `cd /usr/share/locales`
2. `sudo ./install-language_pack ru_RU`
3. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`
4. Restart Apache

Next, use the following php snippet:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'ru_RU.UTF-8');
echo strftime('%A', time());
```

Should output today's day of the week.

Comment: IMHO, both `IntlDateFormatter` (provided that you're running PHP 5.3 with intl installed) and `Zend_Date` are simpler than anything that requires `setlocale()`.