# i translate the website in arbic using polylang plugin but date should not translate in arbic?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlWId.png)

i translate the website in arbic using polylang plugin but date should not translate in arbic? how to convert digits are in Arabic, otherwise using css it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call date as per your need

**In call,You can call it via:**

```
arabicDate($yourdatevari);
```

In function.php file

```
function arabicDate($time)
{
    $months = ["Jan" => "يناير", "Feb" => "فبراير", "Mar" => "مارس", "Apr" => "أبريل", "May" => "مايو", "Jun" => "يونيو", "Jul" => "يوليو", "Aug" => "أغسطس", "Sep" => "سبتمبر", "Oct" => "أكتوبر", "Nov" => "نوفمبر", "Dec" => "ديسمبر"];
    $days = ["Sat" => "السبت", "Sun" => "الأحد", "Mon" => "الإثنين", "Tue" => "الثلاثاء", "Wed" => "الأربعاء", "Thu" => "الخميس", "Fri" => "الجمعة"];
    $am_pm = ['AM' => 'صباحاً', 'PM' => 'مساءً'];

    $day = $days[date('D', $time)];
    $month = $months[date('M', $time)];
    $am_pm = $am_pm[date('A', $time)];
    $date = $day . ' ' . date('d', $time) . ' - ' . $month . ' - ' . date('Y', $time) . '   ' . date('h:i', $time) . ' ' . $am_pm;
    $numbers_ar = ["٠", "١", "٢", "٣", "٤", "٥", "٦", "٧", "٨", "٩"];
    $numbers_en = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];

    return str_replace($numbers_en, $numbers_ar, $date);
}
```

Function referanced here :[Display dates in Arabic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166907/display-dates-in-arabic)