# Checking if date is weekend PHP

Tags: php, date

This function seems to only return false. Are any of you getting the same? I'm sure I'm overlooking something, however, fresh eyes and all that ...

```
function isweekend($date){
    $date = strtotime($date);
    $date = date("l", $date);
    $date = strtolower($date);
    echo $date;
    if($date == "saturday" || $date == "sunday") {
        return "true";
    } else {
        return "false";
    }
}
```

I call the function using the following:

```
$isthisaweekend = isweekend('2011-01-01');
```

Comment: Your `true` and `false` should not be quoted as strings. Also your code should give a parse error and not even run at all because of the stray `}` in your if.

Answer (score 252, accepted):

If you have PHP >= 5.1:

```
function isWeekend($date) {
    return (date('N', strtotime($date)) >= 6);
}
```

otherwise:

```
function isWeekend($date) {
    $weekDay = date('w', strtotime($date));
    return ($weekDay == 0 || $weekDay == 6);
}
```

Comment: If you use PHP < 5 then using `return date('w', strtotime($date)) % 6 == 0` is a little shorter.

Comment: While that does the same thing, I'd say the explicit check is more obvious for someone reading the code.

Comment: Then again that's what comments are for.

Comment: Well, there are people who say that code should be readable without a lot of comments. Good code is readable - and not necessarily short. #CleanCode

Comment: The less code there is the less there is to test and maintain. But if its unreadable its harder to test and maintain. Does there have to be a hard and fast rule about readability, or is it down to experience?

Comment: Beware of variable type. date() returns string. Comparing it to number can create issues. Good practice could be to add a (int) and switch string to number

Answer (score 58):

Another way is to use the **DateTime** class, this way you can also specify the timezone.
Note: PHP 5.3 or higher.

```
// For the current date
function isTodayWeekend() {
    $currentDate = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone("Europe/Amsterdam"));
    return $currentDate->format('N') >= 6;
}
```

If you need to be able to check a certain date string, you can use **DateTime::createFromFormat**

```
function isWeekend($date) {
    $inputDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("d-m-Y", $date, new DateTimeZone("Europe/Amsterdam"));
    return $inputDate->format('N') >= 6;
}
```

The beauty of this way is that you can specify the timezone without changing the timezone globally in PHP, which might cause side-effects in other scripts (for ex. Wordpress).

Comment: Take your upvote, but the pedant in me is warning you when they decide to add an extra day of the week it might just be a weekday :)

Comment: "this way you can also specify the timezone". According to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470617/how-to-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-php/16814230), you can specify the timezone in alternate ways too. I've used your solution though

Answer (score 19):

If you're using PHP 5.5 or PHP 7 above, you may want to use:

```
function isTodayWeekend() {
    return in_array(date("l"), ["Saturday", "Sunday"]);
}
```

and it will return "true" if today is weekend and "false" if not.

Comment: This will only work for English-language sites. It could be modified, but would get cumbersome for sites with multiple languages.

Comment: @Bob Ray oh okay sorry i didn't notice that while I wrote it

Answer (score 12):

Here:

```
function isweekend($year, $month, $day)
{
    $time = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);
    $weekday = date('w', $time);
    return ($weekday == 0 || $weekday == 6);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

The working version of your code (from the errors pointed out by BoltClock):

```
<?php
$date = '2011-01-01';
$timestamp = strtotime($date);
$weekday= date("l", $timestamp );
$normalized_weekday = strtolower($weekday);
echo $normalized_weekday ;
if (($normalized_weekday == "saturday") || ($normalized_weekday == "sunday")) {
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}

?>
```

The stray "{" is difficult to see, especially without a decent PHP editor (in my case). So I post the corrected version here.

Comment: You should also not return quoted true or false - or better still, just return the condition.

Comment: @alex: I use "echo" to confirm the result, so.. that's it. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 3):

For guys like me, who aren't minimalistic, there is a PECL extension called "[intl](http://pecl.php.net/package/intl)". 
I use it for idn conversion since it works way better than the "idn" extension and some other n1 classes like "IntlDateFormatter".

Well, what I want to say is, the "intl" extension has a class called "IntlCalendar" which can handle many international countries (e.g. in Saudi Arabia, sunday is not a weekend day). The IntlCalendar has a method [IntlCalendar::isWeekend](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intlcalendar.isweekend.php) for that. Maybe you guys give it a shot, I like that "it works for almost every country" fact on these intl-classes.

EDIT: Not quite sure but since PHP 5.5.0, the intl extension is bundled with PHP (--enable-intl).

Answer (score 2):

This works for me and is reusable.

```
function isThisDayAWeekend($date) {

    $timestamp = strtotime($date);

    $weekday= date("l", $timestamp );

    if ($weekday =="Saturday" OR $weekday =="Sunday") { return true; } 
    else {return false; }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As opposed to testing the explicit day of the week string or number, you can also test using the relative date `this weekday` of the supplied date.

A direct comparison between the values is not possible without a workaround, as the use of `weekday` resets the time of the supplied date to `00:00:00.0000`.

`DateTimeInterface` objects

```
$date->setTime(0, 0, 0) != $date->modify('this weekday');
```

### `DateTimeInterface` Method

A simple method to implement to ensure the supplied date object is not changed.

```
function isWeekend(DateTimeInterface $date): bool
{
    if ($date instanceof DateTime) {
        $date = DateTimeImmutable::createFromMutable($date);
    }

    return $date->setTime(0,0,0) != $date->modify('this weekday');
}

isWeekend(new DateTimeImmutable('Sunday')); //true
```

### `strtotime` method

With `strtotime` you can compare with the `date('Yz')` format. If the `Yz` value changes between the supplied date and `this weekday`, the supplied date is not a weekday.

```
function isWeekend(string $date): bool
{
    return date('Yz', strtotime($dateValue)) != date('Yz', strtotime($dateValue . ' this weekday'));
}

isWeekend('Sunday'); //true
```

### Example

https://3v4l.org/TSAVi

```
$sunday = new DateTimeImmutable('Sunday');
foreach (new DatePeriod($sunday, new DateInterval('P1D'), 6) as $date) {
    echo $date->format('D') . ' is' . (isWeekend($date) ? '' : ' not') . ' a weekend';
}
```

**Result**

```
Sun is a weekend
Mon is not a weekend
Tue is not a weekend
Wed is not a weekend
Thu is not a weekend
Fri is not a weekend
Sat is a weekend
```