# Checking if date falls on weekday or weekend?

Tags: php

How do you check whether a date in the US format of e.g. *2012-01-01* falls on a weekday or weekend in PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking if date is weekend PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802335/checking-if-date-is-weekend-php)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$weekday = date("w", strtotime("2012-01-01"));
```

This will be 0 for Sunday through 6, Saturday.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php