# How to find get week duration or week range from sunday to friday in php

Tags: php, date

How to find  get week duration or week range from monday to friday for the given date in php.

```
for example i have date
$date = "2013-02-24";
```

Now i want range of date from monday to friday for the month

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9553731/checking-if-date-falls-on-weekday-or-weekend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Try Out this answer.

```
 $date = "2013-02-24";
 $week =  date('W', strtotime($date));
 $year =  date('o', strtotime($date));
 echo "first day of week". $from = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("{$year}-W{$week}-1")); 
 echo "end day of week". $to = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("{$year}-W{$week}-5"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function week_range($date) {
    $ts = strtotime($date);
    $start = (date('w', $ts) == 0) ? $ts : strtotime('last monday', $ts);
    return array(date('Y-m-d', $start),
                 date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next friday', $start)));
}
```

And call it like this:

```
list($start_date, $end_date) = week_range('2009-05-10');
```