# Echo Text only if it's Wednesday

Tags: php, echo

sadly i'm not familar with php, but is it possible to Echo a Text only if it is a specific day of a week? As Example if it's Wednesday to echo "Hey today you have to wash your car?" and if it is not that day to show nothing?

Sinclery Yours

Comment: Please start with some php basic tutorials. We are not a code writing service here nor a school

Comment: I never said i wanted a full code, a tutorial or simlar were also great because i didn't found something on google. So i don't know why you are so angry about.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking if date falls on weekday or weekend?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9553731/checking-if-date-falls-on-weekday-or-weekend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. This wil be your answer.

> The date function Formats a date . It Returns a string formatted according to the given format string.

It accepts 2 arguments.

**1st - (string). Should be valid format. [Check for possible formats](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)**

**2nd - (int). It is optional. It accepts timestamps. The default value will be current time stamp**

```
$day = date('D');
if (strtolower($day)=='wed')
{
    echo "Today is Wednesday";
}
```

Comment: If you make your answer even better than the other ones then you could improve your changes of getting it accepted. You can explain what the code does, in your own words, for example.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen Thank you for pointing me to that. I really like your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
<?php
if (date('D') === 'Wed')
    echo "Hey today you have to wash your car?"
```

read about the [date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function, there's lots of bits it can return

Comment: Thank you, sadly some other was faster

Comment: no problem @Deex, don't forget you can make things cooler by adding extra e.g. if I'm lazy and want to be reminded on the 1st Wed of the month `if (date('D') === 'Wed' and date('j') <= 7)`

Answer (score 0):

Use date('w'):

```
if (date('w')==3)
  print "Hey today you have to wash your car?";
```

Comment: Thank you :) that was what i seeked for, and the smallest solution

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current day of the week using the [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function. The function returns different things depending on what you put in the first argument. You can find what those things are in the documentation (link above). `"w"` tells the function to return the day of the week:

```
$dayOfWeek = date("w");
```

The variable now contains a number representing the day of the week, starting from `0` (Sunday) to `6` (Saturday). In other words:

```
0 = Sunday
1 = Monday
2 = Tuesday
3 = Wednesday
4 = Thursday
5 = Friday
6 = Saturday
```

If you only want to target Wednesday then you can use an `if` block:

```
if ($dayOfWeek == 3) {
    echo 'Hey today you have to wash your car!';
}
```

If you want to target more than one day then you can use a `switch` block:

```
switch ($dayOfWeek) {
    case 0: // Sunday
    case 6: // Saturday
        echo 'Good weekend! Enjoy it!';
    break;
    case 3: // Wednesday
        echo 'Hey today you have to wash your car!';
    break;
}
```