# Given period at least covers one night on the weekend

Tags: php, date, period

I need to check the given period will at least be covers the one night of the weekend(saturday night or sunday night) (refer the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturday-night_stay) about the rule).

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802335/checking-if-date-is-weekend-php) that, how to check the date whether it is fall on weekend or not,

```
function isWeekend($date) {
    $weekDay = date('w', strtotime($date));
    return ($weekDay == 0 || $weekDay == 6);
}
```

But still I am struggle with how to implement a function to get following sample results for given periods,

Sample periods and results:

```
04-01-2016 / 07-01-2016 : false
04-01-2016 / 09-01-2016 : false
04-01-2016 / 10-01-2016 : true (covers saturday night)
03-01-2016 / 07-01-2016 : true (covers sunday night)
04-01-2016 / 14-01-2016 : true (covers a full weekend)
```

The rule should wither start date is falls on weekend or end date is falls on sunday or the period covers at a full weekend.

Comment: So, loop over the dates from begin to end of a period, and check. (Once you found the first Saturday or Sunday night covered, you can end the loop.)

Comment: @CBroe working on it, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you're looking for something like this:

```
function coversWeekend($start, $end) {
    $weekend       = [0, 6]; // 0 for Sunday, 6 for Saturday.

    // Loop over the date period.
    while ($start < $end) {
        if (in_array($start->format('w'), $weekend)) {
            return true;
        }

        $start->modify('+1 day');
    }

    return false;   
}
```

Be warned, there isn't on validation on what the user passes in. You may want to add a check that a valid DateTime object was passed for each parameter.

Hope it helps.

**Edit:** Updated the solution with @honzalilak's feedback.

Comment: Small improvement: you can return true in the if part instead of assigning it to variable and end the loop right away when there is a match with weekend.