# How to find Tomorrow day is "saturday" or not in PHP?

Tags: php, strtotime

This is my code. I am using the `strtotime` function for find the next day is saturday. But my code result is always run `else` part. Where I am wrong.

```
$current_date = date('Y-m-d');

$date = strtotime($current_date); 

$weekDay = date('w', strtotime('+1 day',$date));

if(($weekDay == 'Saturday'))
    echo "Tomorrow is Saturday.";
else
    echo "Tomorrow is not Saturday.";
```

Comment: `var_dump()` your variables to actually *see* what you're dealing with...! Also, `strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))` is the same as `time()`.

Comment: The `w` option for date returns 0-6, not a word.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if date is weekend PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802335/checking-if-date-is-weekend-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will give you 6 as output.
You could change the "6" insteadof "saturday".

```
$date = time(); //Current date 
$weekDay = date('w', strtotime('+1 day',$date));

if(($weekDay == 6)) //Check if the day is saturday or not.
    echo "Tomorrow is saturday.";
else
    echo "Tomorrow is not saturday.";
```

**Result :**

Tomorrow is saturday.

```
NOTE :
0 => Sunday
1 => Monday
2 => Tuesday
3 => Wednesday
4 => Thursday
5 => Friday
6 => Saturday
```

Answer (score 3):

Use 'l' instead "w"

```
$current_date = date('Y-m-d');

$date = strtotime($current_date); 

$weekDay = date('l', strtotime('+1 day',$date));
if(($weekDay == 'Saturday'))
    echo "Tomorrow is Saturday.";
else
    echo "Tomorrow is not Saturday.";
```

Comment: Correctly Working.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It will give you 6 as output.

```
$current_date = date('Y-m-d');

$date = strtotime($current_date); 

$weekDay = date('w', strtotime('+1 day',$date));

if(($weekDay == 6))
    echo "Tomorrow is Saturday.";
else
    echo "Tomorrow is not Saturday.";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is very simple solution using **w** param in date() function

```
if (date('w', strtotime("+1 day")) == 6) {
 // tomorrow is saturday
}
```

or more objective solution

```
if ((new DateTime())->modify('+1 day')->format('w') == 6) {
   // tomorrow is saturday
}
```

- *w* - returns day of week
- *6* - represents saturday

To make it short you can use tenary operator

```
printf("Tomorrow is%s saturday", date('w', strtotime("+1 day")) == 6 ? '' : " not");
```