# zf2 validator - valid only if date is a weekday

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-validate

Using ZF2 \Zend\Validate, is it possible to validate a date only if it is a weekday? So weekends, regardless of month or year, will fail the validation?

The input is a normal text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that `Zend\Validate` has already a validator to check that.

You'll probably need to write your own custom validator to do your check.

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4802362/2718064) to see how to perform the actual check (actually that answer check the converse, but it'll be easy to adapt it)

Comment: You are right (and i should have searched for the opposite condition before posting really) - thanks!