# Filter Working days from weekend php

Tags: php, date, filter, weekday, weekend

I want to show an error if it's not a weekday (you can enter a date in the html section)

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_DE.utf8");
$dateString = strftime('%A' , $dateTimestamp1);
substr($dateString, 0, 2);
if ($dateString == 'So' || $dateString == 'Sa') {
    throw new FormInputException('date', 'Invalid Date');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `date('w', $date)` where `w` will set the result to the numeric representation of the day of the week, where 0 represents Sunday, 1 is Monday ... 6 is Saturday etc. Therefore, with a simple custom function you can determine if a date falls on a weekday:

```
function dateIsWeekday($date) {
    $day = date('w', $date);
    return $day > 0 && $day < 6;
}
```

you can call:

```
if (!dateIsWeekday($dateTimestamp1)) {
    throw new FormInputException('date', 'Date is not a weekday');
}
```

Comment: Great to hear! Can you please mark the answer as correct if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

you did not state clearly what your problem is, because the approach you are using is basically ok. However there are a few things to keep in mind:

1. A simpler way
   PHP already gives you the means to check for weekends (depending on your version of PHP). Check out this question that already has the answer: [Weekend in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802335/checking-if-date-is-weekend-php)
2. Using substr
   This is actually unnecessary. `$dateString = strftime('%a' , $dateTimestamp1);` will already give you the abbreviated string (small %a).
3. Using LC_TIME
   An isuse might be that your time is not actually translated to German. This depends on if the language pack you are using (de-DE.utf8) is installed on your server or not. Actually using PHP's main methods for weekend checks you should not even need to care about things like this (see 1.).

Answer (score 0):

if anybody else got the problem i fixed it- here is the code

```
$dateTimestamp1 = strtotime($this->date);

//setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_DE.utf8");
$day = date('N', $dateTimestamp1);
if ($day == 6 || $day == 7) {
    throw new FormInputException('date', 'Invalid Date');
}
```

Comment: Note that the 'N' parameter is only available from PHP 5.1.0