# Check if 2 given dates are a weekend using PHP

Tags: php, weekend

I have 2 dates like this YYYY-mm-dd and I would like to check if these 2 dates are a weekend.

I have this code but it only tests 1 date and I don't know how to adapt it; I need to add a `$date_end`.

```
$date = '2011-01-01';
$timestamp = strtotime($date);
$weekday= date("l", $timestamp );
$normalized_weekday = strtolower($weekday);
echo $normalized_weekday ;
if (($normalized_weekday == "saturday") || ($normalized_weekday == "sunday")) {
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}
```

Comment: This code is pretty horrible anyway. You'd better roll your own.

Comment: Do you know that you can create a `function` in order to factorize code?

Comment: check this  : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802335/checking-if-date-is-weekend-php)

Comment: You should look into `Carbon`; has the handy method `isWeekend()`. http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: these examples check if 1 date is saturday or sunday, but to check if it's a weekend, the need is also to check if the sunday is the good day after the saturday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use shorter code to check for weekend => `date('N', strtotime($date)) >= 6`.
So, to check for 2 dates — and not just 1 — use a function to keep your code simple and clean:

```
$date1 = '2011-01-01' ;
$date2 = '2017-05-26';

if ( check_if_weekend($date1) && check_if_weekend($date2) ) {
    echo 'yes. both are weekends' ;

} else if ( check_if_weekend($date1) || check_if_weekend($date2) ) {
    echo 'no. only one date is a weekend.' ;

} else {
    echo 'no. neither are weekends.' ;
}

function check_if_weekend($date) {
    return (date('N', strtotime($date)) >= 6);
}
```

Using your existing code, which is slightly longer, following is how you would check for 2 dates:

```
$date1 = '2011-01-01' ;
$date2 = '2017-05-27';

if ( check_if_weekend_long($date1) && check_if_weekend_long($date2) ) {
    echo 'yes. both are weekends' ;

} else if ( check_if_weekend_long($date1) || check_if_weekend_long($date2) ) {
    echo 'no. only one date is a weekend.' ;

} else {
    echo 'no. neither are weekends.' ;
}

function check_if_weekend_long($date_str) {
    $timestamp = strtotime($date_str);
    $weekday= date("l", $timestamp );
    $normalized_weekday = strtolower($weekday);
    //echo $normalized_weekday ;
    if (($normalized_weekday == "saturday") || ($normalized_weekday == "sunday")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of hints:

- [`date('N')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) gives you normalised week day you can test against (no need to use localised strings)
- Wrap it all in a [custom function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) and you're done

Comment: `return in_array(date('N', strtotime($date)), [6, 7,]);`

Comment: also works with `date('w')`, but keep in mind that `'w'` is 0 indexed in stead of 1 indexed, like `'N'` is

Answer (score 1):

Merging multiple answers into one and giving a bit extra, you'd come to the following:

```
function isWeekend($date) {
    return (new DateTime($date))->format("N") > 5 ? true : false; 
}
```

Or the long way:

```
function isWeekend($date) {
    if ((new DateTime($date))->format("N") > 5) {
        return true;
    } 
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the strtotime();  and date() functions to get the day of the date, and then check if is sat o sun

```
 function check_if_weekend($date){
    $timestamp = strtotime($date);
    $day = date('D', $timestamp);
    if(in_array($day, array('sun', 'sat'))
       return true;
    else return false;
    }
```

Comment: thanks doest it also check if's the tomorrow's sunday ?