# Check if object date is weekend (php)

Tags: php, date, object

I've seen the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802335/checking-if-date-is-weekend-php) but, if I apply it to my code, I get the following error:

> Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, object given

This is my code:

```
while (date('N', $EndDate2)>=6){
    ...do stuff..;
}
```

Note: $EndDate2 is an object date

Comment: Error message is pretty accurate.

Comment: check [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and see what `date()` expects to be given.

Comment: @bassxzero Yes but I'm new to php and I don't know how to change an object date to a long

Comment: If you are sure that $EndDate2 is date then could you use in strttotime function strtotime($EndDate2)

Comment: @FerhatBAŞ I've explained it isn't a string: it's an object

Comment: Did you try strtotime

Comment: @FerhatBAŞ I've got an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date()` operates against timestamps, rather than `DateTime` objects. You should use the [`format`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method of the object instead (it takes the same formatting arguments):

```
if ($EndDate2->format('N') >= 6) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for understanding my problems and answering instead of downvoting