# Laravel cron job every day except weekends

Tags: php, laravel-4, cron

I'm using laravel 4 and i need to execute script every Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday at 16:00h. Right now im using method dailyAt(16:00), but i dont want to script execute at Suturday and Sunday. My command looks like this in Kernel.php:

```
$schedule->command("script")->dailyAt("16:00")->sendOutputTo("NUL");
```

Comment: Simple way is checking day in week and execute script for weekdays only https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802335/checking-if-date-is-weekend-php

Comment: I left script to run every day at 16:00 and in code i wrote to check if is Sut or Sun so script wont be executed.

Answer (score 2):

```
$schedule->command("script")->weekdays("16:00")->sendOutputTo("NUL");
```

This one is from Monday to Friday. Take a look at laravel documentation for task scheduling for more [Info!!!](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling)

Comment: I dont know why but this runs my script every 2 minutes

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to limit tasks to weekdays is to chain `weekdays()` method. Like:

```
$schedule->command("script")->weekdays()->dailyAt("16:00")->sendOutputTo("NUL");
```