# get UTC time in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, utc

How can I get UTC/GMT +/- time stamp using PHP's date() function? For example, if I try

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
```

I will get Unix time stamp; but I need to get UTC/GMT time stamp with string GMT/UTC+/-0400 or GMT/UTC+/-1000 based on local timings.

Answer (score 135):

Using [`gmdate`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) will always return a GMT date. Syntax is same as for `date`.

Comment: @sanmai: a Unix timestamp is by definition always UTC. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: @nikc.org: The problem is that gmdate("U"), returns same as time() which is not UTC timestamp if your server system timezone is different. The only way i was able to get real UTC based timestamp was strtotime(gmdate("M d Y H:i:s")), which is different that gmdate("U"), when your server system timezone is different than UTC

Comment: @bksi I'm unable to repeat your described behaviour. (My machine is not on GMT and my UNIX timestamps are correct. Also `gmdate("U") == time()`.) Sounds like potentially buggy behaviour. Double check and file a bug with the PHP project.

Comment: I used simple php script to test the scenario:<? echo time()." === ".strtotime(gmdate("M d Y H:i:s"))."  Timezone: ".date("Z")."\n"; ?>
When i ran it i get this result:
1456342082 === 1456338482  Timezone: 3600
The result of shell command date is:
Wed Feb 24 20:28:11 CET 2016

Comment: @bksi - Perhaps you're confusing internal representation of datetime with external representation of datetime? time w/o a zone specifier vs time with a zone specifier? As nikc (and the documentation) says, `time()` returns "number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT)". Note `GMT`.  The fact that by default your system *converts* this to your timezone for display, is a user convenience. Internally, its always GMT.

Answer (score 121):

A simple **[gmdate()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php)** will suffice

```
<?php
print gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z");
```

Answer (score 74):

As [previously answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16814230/184130), since PHP 5.2.0 you can use the `DateTime` class and specify the UTC timezone with an instance of `DateTimeZone`.

The DateTime [__construct() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) suggests passing "now" as the first parameter when creating a DateTime instance and specifying a timezone to get the current time.

```php
$date_utc = new \DateTime("now", new \DateTimeZone("UTC"));

echo $date_utc->format(\DateTime::RFC850); # Saturday, 18-Apr-15 03:23:46 UTC
```

Comment: The DateTime __construct() documentation no longer suggests omitting the first parameter to get the current time. It now says you should use a string of 'now'.

Comment: Thanks @PaulSkinner, I have amended the answer.

Comment: Thanks, what is the purposes of the backslashes before `DateTime`? Running it myself, it seems to work just fine without them.

Comment: @Snow If this code is inserted into namespaced code, let's say your file has a `namespace A` declaration at the top, PHP will assume `DateTime` to refer to `A\DateTime`, which is wrong. Adding the backslash fixes the issue. It's a good habit to take even if you don't use namespaces yet, in my opinion.

Answer (score 35):

```
$time = time();
$check = $time+date("Z",$time);
echo strftime("%B %d, %Y @ %H:%M:%S UTC", $check);
```

Answer (score 28):

Obtaining UTC date

```
gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Obtaining UTC timestamp

```
time();
```

The result will not be different even you have `date_default_timezone_set` on your code.

Comment: @زياد Thanks for the correction, I have modified my answer

Comment: I thought that gmdate() returns GMT and not UTC.  "Identical to the date() function except that the time returned is Greenwich Mean Time (GMT)".  Am I missing something?  Do these come out equivalent?

Comment: @Jordan In practice UTC and GMT represent the same time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48942916/difference-between-utc-and-gmt

Comment: Of course `time()` returns an integer, while `gmdate` returns a formatted string. So they are only "not different" if you are careful how you use them. Technically, that `gmdate` syntax is identical to `gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());`  That is, by default, the time which is formatted is `time()`.

Answer (score 16):

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() - date("Z"))
```

Answer (score 13):

Other than calling `gmdate` you can also put this code before your rest of the code:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
?>
```

That will make rest of your date/time related calls to use GMT/UTC timezone.

Comment: Not anymore in latest versions of PHP.

Comment: @KhomNazid "UTC" as a parameter is still valid.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php#refsect1-function.date-default-timezone-set-parameters

Answer (score 6):

You can use **gmmktime** function without arguments to obtain the current UTC timestamp:

```
$time = gmmktime();
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);
```

gmmktime will only work if your server time is using UTC. For example, my server is set to US/Pacific. the listed function above echos back Pacific time.

Comment: gmmktime() is deprecated

Answer (score 5):

> with string GMT/UTC **+/-0400** or GMT/UTC **+/-1000** based on local timings

Your custom [format](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters) is just missing `O` to give you the timezone offsets from local time.

> Difference to Greenwich time (GMT) in hours   Example: +0200

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/La_Paz');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s O');
```

> 2018-01-12 12:10:11 -0400

However, for maximized portability/interoperability, I would recommend using the [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date format `c`

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/La_Paz');
echo date('c');
```

> 2018-01-12T12:10:11-04:00

```
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Brisbane');
echo date('c');
```

> 2018-01-13T02:10:11+10:00

You can use also [`gmdate`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) and the timezone offset string will always be `+00:00`

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/La_Paz');
echo gmdate('c');
```

> 2018-01-12T16:10:11+00:00

```
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Brisbane');
echo gmdate('c');
```

> 2018-01-12T16:10:11+00:00

Answer (score 5):

You'd like to use gmdate method to get GMT date.

```
gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

gmdate date-formats resemble those in the date() method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following to get UTC time:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');

$current_date = date("Y/m/d g:i A");

$ist_date = DateTime::createFromFormat(
                        '"Y/m/d g:i A"',
                        $current_date,
                        new DateTimeZone('Asia/Calcutta')
                    );

$utc_date = clone $ist_date;
$utc_date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

echo 'UTC:  ' . $utc_date->format('Y-m-d g:i A');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
     * Converts a local Unix timestamp to GMT
     *
     * @param   int Unix timestamp
     * @return  int
     */
    function local_to_gmt($time = '')
    {
        if ($time === '')
        {
            $time = time();
        }

        return mktime(
            gmdate('G', $time),
            gmdate('i', $time),
            gmdate('s', $time),
            gmdate('n', $time),
            gmdate('j', $time),
            gmdate('Y', $time)
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**You want the actual timestamp (a number)**
If you want to return the numeric timestamp for UTC then this is my understanding of it. The getTimestamp() function is pretty useful.

```
$ts = new DateTime('NOW', new DateTimeZone('UTC')); // This could say UTC or GMT
echo $ts->getTimestamp();
```

I am going to try and provide a little bit of information as a starting point for anyone that is confused by GMT/BST/UTC/DST/WET/CET/EET but this is my interpretation of what I understand - pretty sure it's accurate as far as speaking in layman's terms.

**What is a timestamp?**
A timestamp is a numeric equivalent of the number of seconds since 1st January 1970. Essentially, the point at which the time in Greenwich UK was adopted as the global standard/base-line that all countries agreed to adopt. So because it was adopted at a place in the UK, it just happens that GMT is the same as UTC.

**GMT vs UTC vs DST vs BST vs WET vs CET vs EET**
Arggh!
Okay, so the important bit to understand is that GMT & UTC are the same because they started in the UK London->Greenwich's winter as the origin. Essentially, UTC = GMT+00:00.

Then, at a later time UTC was adopted as the best way to refer to the start of this agreed 1st January 1970 rule to avoid confusing it with the time for UK and similar time zone countries. UTC is the standard. GMT is the time zone for a country/countries.

The bit that gets confusing is when there is Daylight Saving Time (DST).
Now, Britain calls this BST (British Summer Time) which is basically a shortcut for saying GMT+01:00.  Europe (as an example) acknowledge DayLight Saving Time too but when they refer to the change they don't call it BST (British Summer Time) the name it based on the European Timezone they are in.

BTW, if you wanted to know if you're current Time zone is in Daylight Saving Time you can do:-

```
$d = date("I");
```

This returns 1 for "Yes I am" or "0" for "No I am not"

**There are three European Timezones.**
There is the Western European Timezone (WET) which is basically the UK and some other countries because of their alignment on the globe when it spins matches up with GMT.

Then there is Central European time which is where most European countries sit (UTC+01:00) and then Easter European time is (UTC+02:00)

So with that in mind, when you take into account DST (Daylight Saving Time) you can assume that each one of those countries that acknowledges it will update their current standard time by 1 hour.

So UK for example will become GMT+01:00 (because we like to call it GMT) and the shortcut is BST (British Summer Time)

France would call Britain's Summer Time as UTC+01:00 or WET+01:00.

Daylight Saving Time to France is called CEST (Central European Summer Time) which is UTC+02:00 or CET+1:00 (because CET is already known as UTC+01:00)

And with Eastern European Time - you get the idea...

---

I hope that helps a little bit but obviously, you need to do your own research. This link has a good graphic showing the zones and more info. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_European_Time

Answer (score -1):

Below find the PHP code to get current UTC(Coordinated Universal Time) time

```html
<?php
// Prints the day
echo gmdate("l") . "<br>";

// Prints the day, date, month, year, time, AM or PM
echo gmdate("l jS \of F Y h:i:s A");
?>
```

Comment: The OP states: "I need to get UTC/GMT time stamp with string GMT/UTC+/-0400", and if I run the given code, the output does not contain this. Also, the OP stated that he wanted to use `date` for this, which your codes does not contain either.