# Current Date From UTC time zone

Tags: php, mysql, sql

We are storing user timezone into database and I am looking current date from UTC time zone. 
I have timezone data like +5.5, -7, +2.5. and want to get current time from Timezone.

How i can get current date from PHP or MYsql.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655515/get-utc-time-in-php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

//current time zone to UTC
$date = new DateTime($datetime, new DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get()));

//set the time zone as UTC
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

//convert local time to UTC time
$date=$date->format("Y-M-D");

echo $date;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------

//UTC to some other time zone format

$date = new DateTime($datetime, new DateTimeZone("UTC"));

//set the time zone as UTC
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get()));

//convert local time to UTC time
$date=$date->format("Y-M-D");

echo $date;
```