# How to get UTC timestamp in php

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

how to get UTC timestamp in php.. The below doesn't returns UTC timestamp, it is displaying some other timestamp

```
 <?php
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    echo strtotime("now");

    ?>
```

i think, setting default timezone as not been effective?

Comment: Hi, please always remember to Google first. `How to get UTC timestamp in php` takes you to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8655551/187606)

Comment: `time()` would return you a UTC timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
<?php

 print gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z"); 

?>
```

**[Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php)**

Comment: It would return a formatted date, not a timestamp

Comment: 5 minutes more, to accept your answer..

Comment: @thuk: you asked about timestamp and about to accept an answer about formatted date. That's weird

Comment: @zerkms the timestamp return on this format is in UTC , that is what i want

Comment: @thuk: timestamp doesn't represent any timezone - it's just a number of seconds since unix epoch. And the whole phrase - "the timestamp return on this format is in UTC" - doesn't make much sense. `gmdate` is a string with formatted date, it has nothing to do with timestamp.