# Get timestamp by UTC Date in PHP?

Tags: php, date, datetime, timestamp, timezone

How can i know `timestamp` of today at 18.00 UTC with php ?
(obviously i don't know what day is today).

So i tried this:

```
$timestamp_now= time(); 
$today= gmdate("d-m-Y", $timestamp_now);    //output for today 20-02-2020

$output= strtotime($today." 18:00"); //i tried to get timestamp for (utc data)
```

---

For **20-02-2020 18.00 UTC** the timestamp should be:

```
 Epoch timestamp: 1582221600
```

But with my code the output is about **20-02-2020 23.00** (i don't know what time zone):

```
       timestamp: 1582239600
```

What is the error ?

---

**EDIT** i solved my question:

```
$timestamp_now= time(); 

$oggi_giorno= gmdate("d", $timestamp_now); //get utc day for today
$oggi_mese= gmdate("m", $timestamp_now); //get utc month for today
$oggi_anno= gmdate("Y", $timestamp_now); //get utc year for today

$output= gmmktime(18, 0, 0, $oggi_mese, $oggi_giorno, $oggi_anno);

//THE OUTPUT IS: 1582221600
```

The output is correct because is about **20-02-2020 18.00 UTC** so to get timestamp for UTC Date must to use `gmmktime` !

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of get UTC time in PHP https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655515/get-utc-time-in-php

Comment: not clear why you just don't call gmdate like `$utc = strtotime(gmdate("d-m-Y 18:00:00"));` if you need the UTC timestamp for 18:00?

Comment: @mitkosoft tried your suggestion....the wrong output is the same like my code. I want to get timestamp for 18.00 UTC

Comment: @Borja, `echo strtotime(gmdate("d-m-Y 18:00:00"));` gives always `1582221600`. not sure how your code looks like after the change.

Comment: @mitkosoft i solved...see the edit

Comment: overcomplicated as you can achieve the same with a single line.

Comment: @mitkosoft so help me because your suggestion doesn't work :D trust me