# Current_timestamp -> PHP Date()

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I have a field in a database labelled "timestamp" that is recording the current_timestamp.

What PHP code do I need to write in order to get the current_timestamp (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) to display as something a little more reader friendly, i.e. (April 30, 2012 at 3:45pm)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470617/get-current-date-and-time-in-php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Great resource for this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
$dateTimeVariable = date("F j, Y \a\t g:ia");
```

This will give you that format of the current time (which seemed to be what you were getting at), otherwise you need to pass the timestamp in after the date format string.

Comment: won't 't' give the number of days in the month instead of the day indicated by the timestamp?

Comment: Sean, you are the winner of this contest.  But for some reason, the "at" in the date("F t, Y at g:ia") is just coming back as the meridiem and day respectively.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6):

use : `date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $current_timestamp);`

or for format like April 30, 2012 at 3:45pm use :

```
date('F j, Y at g:ia', $current_timestamp);
```

Answer (score 3):

See the documentation for the [date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [strtotime function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

```
date('F j, Y \a\t g:ia', strtotime( $current_time ));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$time = strtotime($DBDataColumn);
strftime('%a, %b %d %Y at %I:%M %p', $time);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Date object

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);
echo $date->format("F t, Y at H:i")
```

Comment: Your lines are good, but people normal not know about class::(acces)funcion :(