# How to get the current time and date through php?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get current date and time in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470617/get-current-date-and-time-in-php)

> Which function in php can return the curretn date?
>
> > so that it takes time which should be in users country there should not be any default time

Comment: What have you done already?

Comment: None of the answers address: "it takes time which should be **in users country**"

Comment: @MikeB yes sir exactly... can u help me with that?

Comment: This is something you could find with a single Google search.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this-

```
echo date('Y-m-d h-i-s');
```

It will give something like : "2013-01-09 01-16-26"

Comment: does the timezone would be different for different country users or would it be some default time?

Comment: The timezone will be the one the server's set to

Comment: For different country PHP have different timezone you need to set it in php.ini file

Answer (score 0):

[a] **strftime()**: Format a local time/date according to locale settings

[b] **date** : Format a local time/date

```
    <?php
    print date('r');
    print "\\n";
    print date('D, d M Y H:i:s T');
    print "\\n";
   ?>
```

Output:

```
   Mon, 23 Apr 2007 01:29:56 +0530
   Mon, 23 Apr 2007 01:35:14 IST
```

and

```
  <?php
   print strftime('%c');
  ?>
```

Output:

```
   Mon Apr 23 01:22:58 2007
```

[demo date](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set the time zone using `date_default_timezone_set()` function in php
Then you need to get the date where ever you need using `date()` function. Thats all..

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/kolkata');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

This will give you something like this

2013-01-09 19:15:48