# PHP equivalent of JavaScript getTime()

Tags: javascript, php, datetime

Suppose I'm running the following JavaScript getTime() function

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var $x = Math.round((new Date()).getTime()/1000);
</script>
```

What would the equivalent code in PHP look like?

Comment: JavaScript time is in milliseconds and PHP time is in seconds. This answer needs to be reopened to answer this question correctly, as none of the answers below is correct, and it is not answered for JavaScript in [How to get the current date and time in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470617/how-to-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-php) The correct answer to the question in case this doesn't get reopened is: `( (string)time() ) . ( (string)intval(microtime()*1000) )` and yes all the parentheses are necessary, otherwise it drops a digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Unix time in php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)

```
$time_stamp = time();
echo $time_stamp;
```

Returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

Answer (score 10):

Try something like this:

```
echo number_format(microtime(true)*1000,0,'.','');
```

or because you are dividing by 1000, most probably you need this:

```
echo number_format(microtime(true),0,'.','');
```

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php
$x = time(); // seconds
$x = microtime(); // milliseconds
?>
```

Check out  [time()](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/7ym-da9) and [microtime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php).

Answer (score 0):

You'd use the php function **time()**. It creates the timestamp for you.

```
<?php 
    $time = time();
?>
```