# Why is date() returning September 2014 instead of Oct 2014

Tags: php, date

The `$ts` returned is correct but the `$moyr` is returning September 2014

```
$cal_date = gregoriantojd(10, 1, 2014);
$ts = jdtounix($cal_date);
$moyr = date("F Y", $ts);
echo $moyr;
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to http://codepad.viper-7.com/RgpxkG

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470617/get-current-date-and-time-in-php/18518844#18518844

Comment: unfortunately on my server it is could this be due to PHP version?

Comment: Check your system's date.also check the default timezone from php.ini.later might not be relevant.

Comment: Gregorian calendar may be off by as many as four years. However, some versions of PHP have it off by a day ... https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44474

Comment: I created a separate page at http://www.productionwidgets.com/month.php? with the same code and it returns September 2014

Comment: It is off on all months by 1

Comment: As I know date() returns wrong date if server date/time is wrong and/or the localisitaion is set wrongly

Comment: Do you live in north or south american continants? If so, your problem may be occured relating local time.　"Oct. 1st 2014, 00:00" in UT is "Sep. 30 2014, 19:00" in local time of New York.

Comment: I'm in California. My browser shows May 2014. http://imgur.com/Asz5Uov

Comment: Currently it it set to $cal_date = gregoriantojd(6, 1, 2014);
$ts = jdtounix($cal_date);
$d = date("F Y", $ts);
echo $d;

Comment: In am in CA.  I added an echo for the unix.  productionwidgets.com/month.php?

Comment: Unix  1401580800  gives May 2014