# I want to know how to display curent time in PHP

Tags: php, time

I want to know how to display time since a user has submitted the form on my website. So for example when the user submits the form I was to display

"Thank-you for your submission. You have been logged in for 0 seconds" depending upon the time that has elapsed." Can  I use the time() function but am not sure to process it.

Comment: When the form loads, save that timestamp in a hidden field then post it to your PHP page and when you output the thank you message get a timestamp again, compute and display the difference :)

Comment: how to create the timestamp. My function time() gives me time since epoch in seconds.

Comment: Yes that's it. thats all you need. When you have 2 different epoch seconds subtract them then you have the number of seconds elapsed. Then you can divide that by 60 to see the number of minutes

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get current date and time in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470617/get-current-date-and-time-in-php)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");//current date

echo date("H:i:s");//current time
```

you can search in net before ask:D

Answer (score 1):

When the user  login store the `time` in a session variable like this:

```
$_SESSION['usertime'] = time();
```

Then when the user submits the form you simply minus the current time from that session variable time.

```
echo "You have been logged in for "  
      . round(abs($_SESSION['usertime']- time()) / 60,2). " minute";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use time function like this.

```
<?php
    $time=time();
    echo($time . "<br>");
    echo(date("Y-m-d",$time));
?>
```

Comment: I don't want to show the date just the time as in you have been logged in for 1 minute or 3 seconds or 0 seconds whatever the case is

Comment: check luthando loot answer that may help you