# How to make php variable the current date

Tags: php, mysql

When user uploads content it enters php varable $date into value of one of the colums on a table. How would you make the php variable the current date, time is not needed just date.

I tried to do this as a string but it shows "CURDATE();" instead of the actual current date

```
$date="CURDATE();";
```

Comment: it should be,`$date = date('Y-m-d');`

Comment: $date=CURDATE(); ... you wrapped the curdate() function in quotes...remove those. as other said $date = date('Y-m-d'); is better. Curdate() is also a mysql function.

Comment: Hello Brian, I tried this method as well and I get Fatal error: Call to undefined function CURDATE() in /home/jeffdbeats2/public_html/soundplum/add.php on line 19

Comment: @jeff Welcome, would like to suggest you to google before asking question, Answer is very common! :)

Comment: `CURDATE()` mysql function. you can not use it directly in php.

Comment: It's good that you got answer. but you can vote-up and mark answer that seems more accurate and given you first.thanks. it will help future users to get reference from your problem. thanks again

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get current date and time in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470617/get-current-date-and-time-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
```

This is documented very well here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Please, at least try to find a solution yourself next time, this is a very basic thing and is easily found by google.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `php` `date()` function. You can use `CURDATE()` in `mysql` query.

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");
```