# PHP Log ip address and date time

Tags: php

Ok on my site i got access to a specific file secured by only allowing whitelisted ips allowed to access the file (all done in php not .htaccess)

else die, it displays an error saying access denied, how do i get it to save the users ip and date + time in a text file, the variable for the users ip is $host

it is not a duplicate because i need to know how to log as a text file.
thanks

Comment: This is the sort of thing where a Google search for something like "PHP write to text file" would be a much better option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the client IP address in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php)

Comment: but how i log to .txt file?

Answer (score 0):

STEP1. Get your ip. 
For more information, [How to get the current date and time in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470617/get-current-date-and-time-in-php) and [How to get the client IP address in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php)

```
$host = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$timezone = date_default_timezone_get();
```

STEP2. To determine whether it is allowed, find if `$host` is in your whitelist (in a file, or MySQL)

STEP3. For writing to file, [just open your custom log file and append](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) `$host.$timezone` to it.

Comment: i already got that, but how do i save it to a text file when someone is not allowed tries to access it?

Comment: @user5675649 Above STEP2 is doing it. You should insert code to check whether the user is allowed or not.