# Unable to understand time() and date() functions

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am trying to get current time and date in order to echo it out on my website. I have the follow snippet:

```
$date_of_msg  = date("Y-m-d");
$time_of_msg  = time();
```

When I echo `$time_of_msg` I get `00:00:00`. I have tried to edit my code based on this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470617/get-current-date-and-time-in-php) but which this approach, when I echo the variable, I get `838:59:59`. I simply want the current time to be displayed in 24 hour format.

In addition to this, I currently have the date formatted to (Y-m-d), which is great because it works. I am trying to format it so that it displays `day, number, year`, i.e. today is 20th Feb, so I want the date to display `Feb 20, 2016`. I have tried the following based on documentation (see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php))

```
$date_of_msg = date("F j, Y")
```

But again, the date displays nothing. Am I missing something?

Comment: `echo $time_of_msg  = time();` => 1455927303 is what I get back. What am I missing here? Or, should I say: what is missing in this question and that you're not telling us? Oh, the mysql stuff. check your column type.

Comment: From one Fred to another; your question's unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the current time in the 24h format just use

```
$time_of_msg = date("H:i");
```

The date part seems correct that way, you must be doing something wrong while displaying it.

Answer (score 1):

`time()` returns a UNIX timestamp while `date()` format a timestamp. Your call `date("Y-m-d")` means the same as `date("Y-m-d", time())`.

Even though the function is called `date()`, it can also format time. You just have to use the correct placeholders. E.g. `date("H:i:s")` would give you a 24h-time like `17:43:23`.

Answer (score 1):

`time()` (unless you override it in some weird fashion) gives you a timestamp, i.e. the amount of seconds which have passed since 1970-01-01 until now. `date()`, however, gives you a string representation of a date, which may or may not include the minutes and seconds - depending on how you choose to format it.

So, if you want to display the time and date to a user, you should probably go for something like

```
$date_of_msg = date("F j, Y H:i:s")
```

The [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) on `date()` gives you an excellent description of available options.

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
<?php
echo date("Y-m-d").PHP_EOL;
echo time().PHP_EOL;
echo date("F j, Y").PHP_EOL;
```

Returns this result, as expected

```
2016-02-20
1455927480
February 20, 2016
```

So what are you doing that you are not actually telling us

Comment: *"So what are you doing that you are not actually telling us"* - the "mysql" stuff. That's what my *Spidey sense* is telling me here Smokey ;-)

Comment: You have been known to be right in the past Ralph @Fred-ii-

Comment: That, and a bit *crazy* ;-)

Comment: A bit ?? And the rest

Comment: *ahem*, sorry... I meant *"a bit more than usual."* ;- or "others".

Comment: OP's not responding or decided to leave it till tomorrow. I, well... am going to go watch the boob tube. Maybe I'll get to see some too.