# Save date and time when* something* is* posted

Tags: php, time

OK does somebody know how to save date and time where something is posted? I am making school website and i add news but I want to get date and time and save it(IK how to save :P). I only know how to use C# version of gettime/getdate

Comment: Start with the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470617/get-current-date-and-time-in-php.

I normally don't say this, but did you try Googling "get current date php"? The first five links are probably what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you already have a form with which you are posting the content. Once you have posted the content, you can include the following php code:

```
$post_time = time();
```

`$post_time` would then contain a timestamp. It represents the amount of seconds that passed after January 1st of 1970 and is a commonly used method of storing time: [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)

If you would like to use that timestamp to display the exact date and time you posted the message, you can do something similar to:

```
echo "Posted on: ".date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A',$post_time );
  //outputs something similar to:
  //Posted on: Monday 8th of August 2005 03:12:46 PM
```

Let me know if that worked for you.