# Convert datetime to GMT timestamp

Tags: php, datetime, datetime-format

I need to find a way to convert a user specified date and time into a GMT timestamp.

Following the answer by Mahdi [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470617/get-current-date-and-time-in-php), I'm using the following code to prototype the conversion

```
$date = new DateTime("09 Jul 2016 18:00:00");
echo gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date->getTimestamp());
```

Which returns

> 2016-07-09 16:00:00

What the response should be is

> 2016-07-09 17:00:00

Because via using other sources I've worked out that the GMT time is 1 hour behind of the local time where I live (UK).

Any ideas why this peculiar behaviour is happening?

Comment: `$date = new DateTime("09 Jul 2016 18:00:00", new DateTimeZone('UTC')); echo $date->format('U');`

Comment: If I format that to `Y-m-d H:i:s` it's giving the timestamp of 2016-07-09 18:00:00, which is the same time...

Comment: You asked for the timestamp, make sure that you have your timezone is set correctly when you render that to a human formatted dte/time value

Answer (score 0):

You never set the timezone to be UTC. Also, it's not necessary to mix `DateTime` functionality with other PHP date functions as `DateTime` has all of the tools you need built in.

```
$date = new DateTime("09 Jul 2016 18:00:00", new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/602895)

Comment: This gives `2016-07-09 16:00:00` which is what I was getting initially.

Comment: My demo says otherwise

Comment: Your latest edit (to set the `DateTimeZone` to `Europe/London`) has **fixed it**! However, if the application I'm building is to be used in other places around the world, is there a way to make that part dynamic?

Comment: Definitely. The timezone value can be placed in a variable and passed to `DateTimeZone()~ just like any other function.