# Can't echo current DateTime in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I added a datetime column in mysql. It takes current timestamp as its value.
I am facing an error when I echo it in php. Saying it is an undefined index.

```
$sql="SELECT `idea-content` FROM `ideas` ";
$result = mysqli_query($mysql_link, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<li>
    <div class='comment-main-level'>
      <!-- Avatar -->
      <div class='comment-avatar'><img src='#' alt=''></div>
      <!-- Contenedor del Comentario -->
      <div class='comment-box'>
        <div class='comment-head'>
          <h6 class='comment-name by-author'><a href='#''>Agustin Ortiz</a></h6>
          <span>".$row['time']."</span>
          <i class='fa fa-reply'></i>
          <i class='fa fa-heart'></i>
        </div>
        <div class='comment-content'>".$row['idea-content']."
        </div>
      </div>
    </div></li>";
        }
```

Table:https://ibb.co/eU9Jd5

Comment: Then the field (as spelled) doesn't exist in the results. Check the spelling of the column name, and if it's correct, check your SQL statement to be sure it's one of the columns returned.

Comment: You selected 1 field but try to output 2 fields.

Comment: So what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You selected 1 field but try to output 2 fields.
The `time` field is missing from your select, aslo you can use `DATE_FORMAT` to format the out of the date

```
$sql="SELECT `idea-content`, DATE_FORMAT(`time`, '%W %M %Y') as `time` FROM `ideas` ";
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: That's it.. I added the time field later on and forgot to add it to the query. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This code will get the date and time of your local machine (PC)

```
echo date("d-m-Y H:i:sa");
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43066760/3471640