# php: Get month's last weekend beginning as DateTime

Tags: php, datetime

I would like to extract beginning DateTime of last weekend of certain month (i.e. March) in current year, using PHP?

```
Example: 

Last weekend of March this year would be: 23-03-2018.
```

Comment: When you say "Last weekend" are you talking about Saturday or Sunday?  You could say strtotime("last saturday of march 2017") and it'll give you your answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour, have a look around, and read through the help center, in particular How do I ask a good question? and What topics can I ask about here?. From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the current date and time in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470617/how-to-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-php)

Comment: @ChrisG Amazing! Didn't know for that trick, I've solved problem. Please post answer so I can mark it.

Comment: @Lululu but that won't work in all cases. If I understand your question case you want a "full" weekend of the month. As Chris suggests will give output 2018-03-31 which is not the last full weekend.

Comment: @Lululu have you looked at my answer?

Comment: @Andreas Yes, thanks for your response, but Chris did previously answered it and I succeeded using it. Thanks again for response.

Comment: @Lululu But chris solution returns incorrect output: https://3v4l.org/hjBhO

Comment: @Andreas My bad. Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the last full weekend (I read the question as that is what you want) you need to find last date of month and look at what day that is.
I use date("w") to get the date number 0 for Sunday and 6 for Saturday.
If the number is 5 or larger a full weekend can't happen that month.

If that is the case I remove a few days from the Unix time and find the previous Friday.

```
$month = "March";
If(date("w", strtotime("last day of ". $month)) >= 5){
    $unix = strtotime("last day of ". $month)-86400*6;
    Echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("previous Friday " .date("Y-m-d", $unix)));
}Else{
    Echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("previous Friday " .date("Y-m-d",strtotime("last day of ". $month))));
}
```

Try it here: https://3v4l.org/O4TDd

Answer (score -2):

I think you should find a solution with [strtotime](https://www.php.net/strtotime)

You can iterate months with

```
strtotime("-1 months"));
strtotime("1 months"));
```

and then get the last week end days dates with

```
strtotime("last saturday");
strtotime("last sunday");
```

Try :

```
echo strtotime("+[your variable]"+ months last sunday");
```

Where [your variable] is the number of months before or after current month

**Edit :**

after seeing **@ChrisG** answer in the comments, the best solution is in fact :

```
 $month = [your month variable];
 echo strtotime("last saturday of "+ $month);
```