# Post response time from form with PHP

Tags: php

I want to be able to include

```
$forename = $_POST["forename"];
$surname = $_POST["surname"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];
```

Would you use something like;

`$timestamp = $_POST["??"];`

I don't know how you'd then get the time in the format DD/MM/YYY HR:MIN:SEC?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the current date and time in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470617/how-to-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no need to 'post' the time, the server already knows it:

```
$timestamp =date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
```

see all date format options: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php