# Wanting to display current date but instead it display the date of the end of month

Tags: php, html

So I was trying to display the current Day and date of today using php but instead it displays the last day of the month. I did tried to display the last day of the month before i tried ti display the current date of today and it works.

I tried to re do in another new php page but the result is still the same.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php`enter code here`
    echo date("D - t - m - Y");
    ?>
</body>
```

I just wanted to display my current date at my place only.

Comment: Read the docs on [`date`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php): _“`t`: Number of days in the given month”_.

Comment: oh okay. my bad then. Thanks MAN! but my problem is now that it displays the date and day of tomorrow instead of today. Here is my code 

<?php
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
        echo date("D - d - m - Y");
        ?>

@SebastianSimon

Comment: Have you read [How do I get the current date and time in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/470617/4642212)?

Comment: @SebastianSimon i did. But the output is ' 08/03/2019 01:24:14 pm '. While the date today is supposed to be '08/02/2019 10.25.14pm' .

Comment: @SebastianSimon this is what i tried btw , " <?php
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
        $date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
        echo $date;
        ?> "

Comment: Your code [seems to work for me](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/7qdw-ccjy).

Comment: @showdev i tried it on another laptop, it works correctly. I dont understand why mine is having problems like this.

Comment: Is the PHP server you have running locally on the laptop or are both computers accessing the same server?

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this.

```
$timestamp = time();

data('Y-m-d H-i-s', $timestamp);
```

You can class use DateTime class.

```
$d = new DateTime('NOW', new DateTimeZone('Europe/London');

echo $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s);
```

You can try out different formatting options and choose which best suits your needs.

Edit, adding an echo, and also the timezone option That's all that is needed to echo out the object value, DateTime and DateTimeZone are inbuilt classes of PHP so you should have no issues using them.

Per your comment, I believe that your computers time zone may be incorrect or the php versions default time zone.

Comment: I dont understand how to use this. Whats weird is that, i could get the correct date and time if i code it on another laptop. But its wrong on mine. Could it be my laptop is having problem? if it does, what is the problem ? T_T and im sorry i couldnt understand your code.

Comment: Okay, then it seems you have an incorrect timezone on your computer set. Check that out in your computers settings. As for how to use this, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
    $dt = new DateTime();
    echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   ?>

    Result:- 2019-08-2 02:26:26
```