# How to get a date in the current format?

Tags: php, wordpress

How to get a date in the format 5 - 7 Jan

```
if (get_field('event_from')) {
    echo $datefrom->format('d.m.Y').' - ';
  }
```

return  21.01.2020 - 22.01.2020

But I need a date in a different format   for example `5 - 7 Jan`
Please help.

Comment: Did you have checked available `date()` formats, together with provided examples there? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the current date and time in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470617/how-do-i-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ACF-field is a datepicker, you could configure the return format in the field it self.
Setting it to `j M` will give you the value "5 Jan"

'j' is numeric representation of day without a leading zero.
'M' is a short textual representation of a month, three letters.

[image: ACF Datepicker-field]

Check the PHP-manual for more information:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Once the field is configured to return the date formated as above, you can just append the value to your string.

```
$date_string;

if (get_field('event_from')) {
   $date_string = get_field('event_from') . ' - ';
}

if (get_field('event_to')) {
   $date_string .= get_field('event_to');
}

echo $date_string;
```